# Regex for textbox to accept only numbers, comma and not 0, decimal or special characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I am looking for a regex to accept only numbers and comma but not 0,decimal,special characters,negative numbers and white-space between the numbers.It can allow White-space at the start and end of the value.Also It should allow 0 for 10,100,20 but I don't want the textbox to allow a single digit zero.

I have tried multiple options but I couldn't find one that solve my problem.

```
string testAnswer = textbox.value;
Regex answerRegex = new Regex(@"\s+(?<!-)[1-9][0-9,]*\s+");
if (testAnswer.Contains(","))
{
    testAnswer = testAnswer.Replace(",", "");
    Response.Write(testAnswer);
}
Match answerMatch = answerRegex.Match(testAnswer.Trim());
if (testAnswer == String.Empty || !answerMatch.Success)
{
    valid = false;
    answer.CssClass = "error";
}           
else
{
    answer.CssClass = "comp";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do what you want.

```
(\s+|^)(?<!-)[1-9][0-9,]*(\s+|$)
```

EDIT: I think I figured out your problem in your code. You're only checking based on `Success` property.
You need to check `answerMatch.Groups` in your code as well.

If you checked `answerMatch.Groups[0]` when you enter `7+9` string, you will realize that the match only matches `7` and discards the rest (+9) of the string.

Ok, I have tested this more extensively and I'm sure that this now works. I've modified your code a little bit so I can use it to demonstrate my test.

```
        string testAnswer = "7 7+9700 700 007 400 -7 8";
        bool valid = true;
        string retVal = "";
        Regex answerRegex = new Regex(@"(\s+|^)(?<!-)[1-9][0-9,]*(\s+|$)");
        if (testAnswer.Contains(","))
        {
            testAnswer = testAnswer.Replace(",", "");
            retVal = testAnswer;
        }
        MatchCollection answerMatch = answerRegex.Matches(testAnswer.Trim());
        if (testAnswer == String.Empty || answerMatch.Count <= 0)
        {
            valid = false;
            retVal = "error";
        }           
        else
        {
            retVal = "comp";
            foreach(Match m in answerMatch) {
                Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[0].Value);
            }
        }
```

`testAnswer` holds my test string to be checked.
The output of the test program is as follows:

```
7 
 700 
 400 
8
```

That output proves that it rejects negative numbers as well as special characters within the number string.

As for the regex string `(\s+|^)(?<!-)[1-9][0-9,]*(\s+|$)` here is the breakdown:

- `(\s+|^) matches either the beginning of a string or leading whitespaces.
- (?

  [1-9][0-9,]* matches the numbers you are interested in including commas.

  (\s+|$) matches either trailing whitespaces or end of the string.

Comment: Oh, you want it to accept both negative and positive numbers?

Comment: ah...I want it to accept only positive numbers but ur regex accepts -ve numbers too....

Comment: My mistake, it should be the expression in my edited answer instead.

Comment: sorry,if I enter 7+9,it accepts but it shouldn't be.

Comment: Would probably need to check your code to see how it's using the regex. I've tested the regex on several online regex testers and none of them accepts 7+9

Comment: I tested your code with my regex. It seems to work for me and does not accept `7+9` and sets`valid` to `false`. Can you post your test string?

Comment: I have revised my answer after I have run the code you posted and debug it a bit. Check to see if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right it should be

```
Regex answerRegex = new Regex(@"^[1-9][0-9]*$");
```

The `*` instead of the `+` lets pass 1, 10, etc.